# Find integer $n$ that satisfies $(\lg n)^{2^{100}} <\sqrt{n}$ with $n > 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, logarithms

If $(\lg n)^{2^{100}} < {n^{1/2}}$, where $\lg$ is the [binary logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm), then

$$(\lg n)^{2^{101}} < n$$
$$2^{101}\lg \lg n < \lg n$$
$$101 < \lg \lg n - \lg \lg \lg n$$

I don't know that whether I assume that $n = 2^x$.
Anyway suppose that $n = 2^x$, then $\lg \lg \lg n = \lg \lg x$.

So, suppose that $x = 2^y$ (it's ambiguous), then $101 < y - \lg y$
therefore, $y = 108$, $n = 2^{2^{108}}$.

I'm curious that there is exact solving method. Because I'm not sure, if $n = 2^{2^{108}} - 1$, what happens??

Comment: Depends if you are asked to find all solutions or just one solution.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I wanna find minimum solution

Comment: what about trivial solution like 1 or any other ?

Comment: Is log is to the base 10 ? , if yes than n equal to or less than 10 will satisfiy your inequality. for ngreater than 10 I don't think it will satisfy this equation

Comment: @MurtuzaVadharia lg is binary logarithm. it means base 2.

Comment: Well the smallest $n$ such that $\lg\lg\lg n$ is even defined is 4:

$\lg\lg\lg 2^2 = \lg\lg 2 = \lg 1 = 0$

So your answer has to be greater than 4.

Answer (score 0):

One such $n$ will be:

$$n = 2^{2^{2^{7}}}$$

If you substitute the $n$ in the inequality you have shown:

$$(\lg{n})^{2^{101}} < n$$

by this number, then after some reductions you'll get a correct inequality below:

$$108 < 128$$

The number $2^{2^{2^{7}}}$ *doesn't* look like a minimal number with such property. Finding a minimal such number is another and much more difficult problem.